# Build simulink blocks with relational operators

Tags: matlab, simulink

How to build the simulink blocks equivalent to below statement.

```
if((In1 == In2) || (In3 != In4))
{
    SubSystem1(In5);
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Take a look at [**Relational Operator**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/relationaloperator.html) and [**Logical Operator**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/logicaloperator.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is in the comment and here is a pictorial view:

[image: Simple Logical Model]

However, if you're going to be doing a lot of logic based code you'll want to look at Stateflow, if you have that product available.

Comment: Thanks you macduff and pm89.